# HARMAN SDK 50.2.2.4 - execution failed for task ':app:lintvitalrelease'. error

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, actionscript-3, harman

Good day, (Trying to build an Android release) anyone who also encounter this problem? I would like to ask for fix? Thank you.

used:

- AS3
- HARMAN SDK 50.2.2.4
- VS CODE STUDIO

Found some solution from other post but it seems it's for jave case? or Android Studio? I don't have build.gradle on my folder either.

Thank you in advance for the correction/answer.